# Question about ideals of quotient ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I found in a book that $\frac{Z[i]}{(3)} \approx \frac{\frac{Z[X]}{(X^2+1)}}{(\overline{3})}$, where $(\overline{3})$ is ideal generated by $\overline{3}$ in $\frac{Z[X]}{(X^2+1)}$. And after that, it says that $(\overline{3}) = \frac{(3,X^2+1)}{(X^2+1)}$. My question is: Why $(\overline{3}) = \frac{(3,X^2+1)}{(X^2+1)}$ ? What Isomorphism theorem is this?

Comment: No, you don't need $(3) \approx \frac{(3,X^2+1)}{(X^2+1)}$ here; you can't "divide" an isomorphism by another anyway (i.e., you cannot conclude $A/B \approx C/D$ from $A \approx C$ and $B \approx D$). For instance, $\mathbb Z \approx \mathbb Z$ and $2\mathbb Z \approx 4\mathbb Z$ (as abelian groups), but $\mathbb Z / 2\mathbb Z \not\approx \mathbb Z / 4\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @darijgrinberg sorry, I reformulated the question because it wasn't very clear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\langle\overline{3}\rangle = \frac{\langle 3, X^2 + 1\rangle}{\langle X^2 + 1\rangle}$ is not merely an isomorphism; the two objects are literally equal as sets.

So consider any $\overline{a}(X) \in \langle\overline{3}\rangle$. Then for some $b(X) \in \mathbb Z[X]$
$$
\overline{a}(X) = \overline{3} \ \overline{b}(X) = [3 + \langle X^2 + 1\rangle][b(X) + \langle X^2 + 1\rangle] = 3b(X) + \langle X^2 + 1\rangle
$$ which is in $\frac{\langle 3, X^2 + 1 \rangle}{\langle X^2 + 1\rangle}$ because $3b(X) \in \langle 3, X^2 + 1 \rangle$.

Conversely consider any $\overline{a}(X) \in \frac{\langle 3, X^2 + 1 \rangle}{\langle X^2 + 1\rangle}$. Then for some $b_1(X), b_2(X) \in \mathbb Z[X]$
$$
\overline{a}(X) = [3b_1(X) + (X^2 + 1)b_2(X)] + \langle X^2 + 1\rangle = 3b_1(X) + \langle X^2 + 1\rangle
$$ which is in $(\overline{3})$.

Comment: Ok. Thanks you!! I think I now understand. So if I have more generally $\frac{\frac{R}{I}}{(a)}$ I can write it as $\frac{\frac{R}{I}}{\frac{(a,I)}{I}}$ where $R$ is a ring and $I$ is an ideal of $R$.

Comment: @MathLearner That is a much more general situation; you can try and mimick the above proof to see if it holds up.